Food processor unable to grind bread cubes
My homemade sourdough bread dries so hard the food processor or blender cannot grind into breadcrumbs. What else can I try?

Use different bread, or try to make one that doesn't turn into diamond? Or try a grater, we generally use that...

If the issue is that the bread has gone stale, you might be able to bring it back by putting it in a brown paper bag, wet the outside of the bag, then bake it.  Once it’s warmed through, it might grind up better… but it could also turn into a gummy mess if it gets too much moisture in it

It might be helpful if you tell us what's your end goal. Are you just trying to make breadcrumbs or are you repurposing old / stale bread?


A mortar and pestle.
A hammer and a plastic bag. Tightly woven fabric bag should also work, if reducing plastic use.
Not waiting so long before attempting to grind it into crumbs.


If the problem is that the chunks go round and round, occasionally getting crumbs knocked off them, pulsing helps, as does putting more in there to start with. If I only want a few breadcrumbs I use the mini chopper attachment meant for nuts, herbs, and even coffee beans. My food processor also has a grater disc that works on bread. I don't often use it because it works better on very dry bread.
If I want dry crumbs (for storage) I crumb the bread fresh or lightly dried, then dry the crumbs in the oven. That's normally with commercial sandwich bread, such as when I had the crusts left over from 10 loaves, but it works better than drying the bread first. I can estimate my consumption fairly well so rarely end up with it that hard accidentally.
